# rkhunter - deleted files - whitelist issues

Tags: whitelist, rkhunter

I am working to secure a fresh Debian LAMP deployment and decided to include rkhunter (v1.4.2) in my security solution.
I have run it using the following options:
`rkhunter -c --enable all --disable none --skip-keypress`
All checks completed positive or skipped but for one, the deleted files check.
After a quick look in the .log file I found the culprits to be:

> [19:59:10] Info: Starting test name 'deleted_files'
>   [19:59:11]   Checking running processes for deleted files    [ Warning ]
>   [19:59:11] Warning: The following processes are using deleted files:
>   [19:59:11]          Process: /usr/sbin/mysqld    PID: 1480    File: /tmp/ib5VMAPQ
>   [19:59:11]          Process: /usr/sbin/apache2    PID: 1792    File: /run/lock/apache2/ssl-cache.1247
>   [...]   # a couple more repetitions here, with different PIDs
>   [19:59:11]          Process: /usr/sbin/apache2    PID: 1813    File: /run/lock/apache2/ssl-cache.1247

I judged these to be harmless/legit and proceeded to whitelist these processes/files.
In `/etc/rkhunter.conf` I found the line
`#ALLOWPROCDELFILE=/usr/sbin/mysqld:/tmp/ib*` and un-commented it. I also added `ALLOWPROCDELFILE=/usr/sbin/apache2:/run/lock/apache2/ssl-cache.*` below the list of commented examples.
Unfortunately, when running rkhunter (with the same options) again I still receive the exact same warnings.
Do I need to enable the whitelisting in general or do something else additionally?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: This was a known issue with RKH. Quote taken from my sourceforge ticket: `The CVS version has fixes in it for the ALLOWPROCDELFILE when using wildcards. (Bugs #114 and #129) The wildcard/globbing was being handled incorrectly.`

Answer (score 0):

```
ALLOWPROCDELFILE=/usr/sbin/mysqld
ALLOWPROCDELFILE=/usr/sbin/apache2
```

or

```
ALLOWPROCDELFILE=/usr/sbin/mysqld:/tmp/ib5VMAPQ
ALLOWPROCDELFILE=/usr/sbin/apache2:/run/lock/apache2/ssl-cache.1247
```

The PID is different in case by case, so I think the second choice is not realistic. I'm not sure why RKH does not work correctly, but it does not been expanding regexes in $ALLOWPROCDELFILE(S).

or

If you can rewrite RKH script

```
--- rkhunter        2015-12-07 03:28:53.000000000 +0900
+++ rkhunter.neu    2016-03-30 13:33:19.328416849 +0900
@@ -13395,7 +13395,7 @@
FNAMEGREP=`echo "${RKHTMPVAR3}" | sed -e 's/\([.$*?\\]\)/\\\\\1/g; s/\[/\\\\[/g; s/\]/\\\\]/g'`
- if [ -n "`echo \"${FNAME}\" | grep \"^${FNAMEGREP}$\"`" ]; then
+ if [ -n "`echo \"${FNAME}\" | grep \"^${RKHTMPVAR3}$\"`" ]; then
   PROCWHITELISTED=1
  fi
 else
```